# how to read JSON data (Dataset contains many table) in jquery to bind mutiple dropdown at a time

Tags: jquery, cordova, dataset

While developing an android app using apache cordova phonegap, I want to bind multiple dropdowns once when page loads.

I used web API contoller method to fetch data code as follows:

```
  public DataSet GetDDL()    
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                GetCompany user = new GetCompany();
                con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "SP_ONLINE_APPLICATION_DROPDOWN_FILL";
                 con.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
           // lblMsg = ex.Message();
             }
            finally
            {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            }
            return ds;
        }
```

getting data as

```
{"Table":[{"intDist_Id":664,"vc_Dist_Name":"---"},                 {"intDist_Id":14,"vc_Dist_Name":"Adilabad"},        {"intDist_Id":508,"vc_Dist_Name":"Agra"}],
"Table1":[{"intCity_Id":600,"vcCity_Name":"--"},    {"intCity_Id":503,"vcCity_Name":"Aarmori"}]}
```

I want to read both tables: to fill dropdown

Jquery code is like

```
 var uri = 'http://localhost:6584/api/ChangeOfName/Getddl';
    var testDdl1 = $('#ddDistrict');
  var testDdl2 = $('#ddCity');
   $.getJSON(uri)
    .done(function (data) {

       $.each(data, function (key, item) {
           if(key=="Table")
           {
               var option = $("<option/>");
       option.attr("value",item.intDist_Id).text(item.Disvc_Dist_NametName);
               testDdl.append(option);
           }
       })
       $.each(data, function (key, item) {
           if(key=="Table1")
           {
               var option = $("<option/>");
               option.attr("value", item.intCity_Id).text(item.vcCity_Name);
               testDdl2.append(option);
           }
       })
   }
)
```

but found 'item.intDist_Id' undefined. Why?

Comment: But a breakpoint on your .done function and see if data contains what you expect.

Comment: Yes, i get data what i expect in 'data', but found' item.values' undefined

Comment: then I think my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript treats objects as something like the Dictionaries in C#. So the jQuery each loops through key/value pairs in your JSON. In this case: Table and Table1 and their respective array values. The array does not have a property `intDist_Id`, so it returns undefined.

You'll have to loop through the items array value to get the actual objects with the properties `intDist_Id`, etc.

```
$.each(data, function (key, items) {
  $.each(items, function(index, item) {
    if(key=="Table")
    {
      var option = $("<option/>");
      option.attr("value",item.intDist_Id).text(item.Disvc_Dist_NametName);
      testDdl.append(option);
    }
    else if(key=="Table1")
    {
      var option = $("<option/>");
      option.attr("value",item.intDist_Id).text(item.Disvc_Dist_NametName);
      testDdl.append(option);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Yes :)  it works for  me.. thanks Thomas, Nice explained

Comment: Glad to know it helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   alert("Your Results: " + data[i].pk_records_id);
  // you need to write each key name here
}
```